# Clustering Similar Histograms

Tags: r, clustering

I have 608 users that participated in 58000 charging events. I am trying to cluster them based on their distribution of events. Or basically I am planning to cluster the histograms with similar distributions. What would be the best way to approach that?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the nature of your data. Could you possibly include an image of one of the histograms or explain further what you mean by an individual's "distribution of events"?

Comment: @RyanVolpi I grouped my data by user ids and skim() them all. Therefore, I have 608 histograms that I want to cluster them based on similar patterns/distributions they are following. The x-axis ranges from 0 to 100 with 5 breaks. and the y-axis is their frequencies. I think it should be the univariate clustering based on frequencies and I came across Gaussian Mixture Model EM Algorithm which can't work because not all histograms following Gaussian Distribution. And now I found poLCA which I am not sure it works. Let me know if this is a better explanation of data.